# vba htmldocument How can I delete a specific element

Tags: vba, removechild, dom

I am writing the code in VBA.
How can I delete a specific element?
Thank you

```
Dim html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

Dim document As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Set document = html.createDocumentFromUrl("http://example.com/", vbNullString)

' wait download
Do While document.readyState <> "complete"
Loop

' Insert I Can
Call document.DocumentElement.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", "<div>test</div>")

' I want to delete a specific element here But I fail
' Call document.removeNode("specific element")
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant remove elements, but you can remove nodes, which is more or less the same.

```
Function DelTagById(strData As String, strID As String) As String

    On Local Error GoTo MyError

    Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
    Dim Node As IHTMLDOMNode

    DelTagById = strData
    If strID = "" Then GoTo MyExit

    Set HTMLDoc = New HTMLDocument
    HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = strData

    Set Node = HTMLDoc.getElementById(strID)
    If Node Is Nothing Then GoTo MyExit
    Node.parentNode.removeChild Node

    DelTagById = HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML

MyExit:
    Set Node = Nothing
    Set HTMLDoc = Nothing
    Exit Function
MyError:
    'Handle Error
    Resume MyExit

End Function
```

Comment: I have tried the option above, but trying to save the response into an object of type IHTMLDOMNode, I get a "type mismatch" error.

Node = html.getElementsByTagName("script")